# Saber en que computadora está logueado un usuario en un medio de AD

Tags: powershell, directorioactivo

Navegando e investigando en internet se encontró el siguiente script de powershell:

```
function Get-LoggedOnUser
 {
     [CmdletBinding()]
     param
     (
         [Parameter()]
         [ValidateScript({ Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1 })]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
         [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
     )
     foreach ($comp in $ComputerName)
     {
         $output = @{ 'ComputerName' = $comp }
         $output.UserName = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $comp).UserName
         [PSCustomObject]$output
     }
 }
```

Al ejecutarlo "Get-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName Computer1" se obtiene la siguiente información:

**Computer name**
Computer1

**User name**
User1

Es decir, obtengo el usuario que está usando la máquina que estoy buscando. 
Pero yo quiero que haga lo contrario, yo quiero buscar el usuario y que me devuelva la máquina que está usando.

Hay alguna forma de hacer lo que quiero usando el mismo script o basandose en el?

Answer (score -1):

Yo también estoy muy muy interesado en conocer las modificaciones al script planteado para obtener el nombre de máquina en el que está logueado un usuario dentro de un dominio.

Alguien puede aportar algo??

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Hola Manu, el apartado de respuestas esta para responder a la pregunta en si, los comentarios y opiniones se escriben en comentarios. A pesar de que aun no tienes la reputación necesaria para comentar este no es lugar para ponerlo. Mira [answer] y pasate por el [tour] para mas información.